# spring properties injection without using @Configuration bean

Tags: spring, spring-properties

I want to load a property file into a spring bean.
I found two approaches :

1. configure in xml as `<util.properties>` and inject using `@Resource` or `@Autowired`
2. Use @PropertySource along with the @Configuration bean.

I do not want to create @configuraiton bean for this scenario since all spring configurations are maintained in xml.

If i follow the first approach - i dont have the below option to handle the scenario of missing property file
@PropertySource(value="classpath:missing.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)

I want the entire property file to be injected since this is lookup file and different keys will be accessed based on the logic. ( hence the context property place holder will not help )

Is there any way i can inject a property file into a bean and also handle the missing file scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it like below

```
<bean id="myLookUp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property>
   <property name="locations">
      <list>
        <value>classpath:myLookUp.properties</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```